# Getting info from a website using indexOf

Tags: java, string, web-scraping

I'm trying to get information from an API, and I just can't figure out how to use String.indexOf to get info from this line.
I'm self taught and never got to a point where I used indexOf until this point, I've tried looking online for a tutorial on how to use indexOf, but all I could find was just find particular letters in a String, and not just get a string from a line.

I've tried changing the value of indexOf multiple times with no success. ID is properly setup, because someone helped me with it, but I figured I need to get a name also, which I couldn't figure out.

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + 
args[0]); //args[0] == name of player
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream isr =con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    int startOfID = line.indexOf("\"id\"") + 4;
    int startOfValueID = line.indexOf("\"", startOfID) + 1;
    int endOfValueID = line.indexOf("\"", startOfValueID);
    // Figure out Name indexOf
    int startOfName = line.indexOf("\"name\"") + 2;
    int startOfValueName = line.indexOf("\"", startOfName);
    int endOfValueName = line.indexOf("\"", startOfValueName);
    Name = line.substring(startOfValueName, endOfValueName);
    UUID = line.substring(startOfValueID, endOfValueID);
    sender.sendMessage(Name + " | " + UUID); // ignore (debugging 
    purposes)
    strUUIDCut = UUID.substring(0,8) + "-" + UUID.substring(8,12) + "- 
    " + UUID.substring(12,16) + "-" + UUID.substring(16,20) + "-" + 
    UUID.substring(20,32);
}
```

No errors are being thrown. I'm expecting to get a name from the API. Whether it be a 3 letter name or a 15 letter name.

Comment: Debug the application. Set a breakpoint. Check the values, find the problem. That's nothing you can solve without running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your lines look something like this:

```
"id"="1", "name" = "foo"
```

When parsing for the id, you are retrieving the start of `"id"` (0) and you correctly add the length of the substring (4). Then, starting from there you retrieve the start of the actual ID value by searching for the index of the next `"` character.

Now, you should do the same with the name. The `"name"` substring is 6 characters long. Therefore, you should add 6 instead of 2 when calculating the `startOfName`:

```java
int startOfName = line.indexOf("\"name\"") + 6;
```

Then, because the actual name only starts *after* the next `"` character:

```java
int startOfValueName = line.indexOf("\"", startOfName) + 1;
```

Again equivalent to what you do with the ID.